# CakePHP: Override template variables for an view element

Tags: templates, cakephp, view, element

I'm using an viewelement inside a view and I need to override a templatevariable which was set in the controller. I pass a key-value-array into the element, but for that key it has no effect. Other variables, which are not defined before I can use inside the element. Is there a trick to do that or do I need another variable for that?

Inside Controller

```
$this->set('mykey', 'myvalue');
```

Inside Template

```
echo $this->element('myelement', array('mykey' => 'anothervalue'));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested the setup you've described and the variable set by the second element parameter is used instead of the variable set in the controller. So "myelement" echoes "anothervalue" as is expected.

It could be that element [caching is enabled](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1083/Caching-Elements), though you have to specify this as a parameter for the `$this->element()` call.

Comment: Thank you. Now, and I don't know why, it suddenly works as expected. I guess the cache was kidding me. Anyway, I get the result I need.